# Align vertices between two edges

Tags: modeling

The problem is that I have two edges on the correct height. Now I want to align the vertices between those edges to make a smooth transition.

But I can't figure out how to do this without moving the ends which have the correct height.

Does anybody has a suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is LoopTools addon way.
Select edges on the border you want to stay untouched. Run LoopTools addon > Curve operator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way - more accurate.
Select the middle vertices.
Go to Tool Tab
Click on Smooth Vertex
Untick the X and Y axes in the settings area down below. I set Repeat to 200, but then pressed "Smooth Vertex" a few times more until it was perfectly straight.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more round about way to do it than necessary, but you could

1. Select the middle vertices and scale them flat on the Z axis
2. Select one of these vertices and note the Z value in the Properties box.
3. Right click on one of the end vertices and note its Z location also.
4. Work out the difference between the two heights - let's say it's 0.3.
5. Select all the middle vertices again and type G Z 0.3 (grab and move on Z axis 0.3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I tried it. However, this only levels the middle vertices to the top edge, what I want a diagonal alignment between the edges.

Comment: Can't you select the middle vertices, then, and rotate them, then adjust the height of them all again - maybe a bit rough but better than nothing till you get a better answer. I overlooked the difference in height between the two ends.  If you put the 3D cursor at the top end before you rotate, and set pivot point to 3D cursor, you only need to rotate, not adjust height.  If it's hard to rotate accurately, you can press Shift while you rotate and that slows it down, so you can be more careful.

Comment: Thanks Susan, I used this method for now.